# How do I manage Wordpress application to get 5000 users logged in at a same time?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, nginx, wordpress-theming, nginx-config

I have created a wordpress application, last year and it got crashed. when 1000 users are trying to signin at the same time.. can someone please suggest how do I manage users and signing activity. I am sure approx 4000 to 5000 users will go for it.

What will be solution for server not crashed, May be modification in server can help and I should make changes?

Previous year nginx server (we have own server) configuration: 4 VCPU/16GB RAM/200GB root space

Please suggest if I have to use any technology/framework or any modifications on server is required?

How to manage the load balancing on server and virtual testing of heavy users before going live.

Comment: that has nothing todo with programming, it is maybe a fit for serverfault, but i don't know enough about them if that uis enough infrmation

Comment: personally I have never dealt with that kind of traffic to a WordPress website, sounds to me it would require some kind of server load balancing. so I agree with @nbk that it is more likely a question for serverfault

Comment: Traffic is always tricky, most of regular cheap hosting are not ment for that kind of usage. You're splitting your space and network with others on a same virtual machine. I can suggest using AWS EC2, usage, network and pricing are self balanced which is perfect for growth.

Comment: Thanks for the response, can anyone let me know about the server configuration which help to handle traffic on the website.

I have my own server and can modify accordingly.

Comment: Hello guys can anyone provide me configuration for the server which can handle signing activity  of 4000 to 5000 users at same time.